# How to interact with a CalDAV server from Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, caldav

I need to create events on a calendar server using CalDAV from within a Ruby (Rails to be precise) Application. I have looked at some different libraries and done some googling.

I looked at ri-cal ( http://ri-cal.rubyforge.org/rdoc/ ) But wasnt sure if it supported sending data toa server or if I had to do that myself,

this looked promising http://www.local-guru.net/blog/pages/rubycaldav , but it says it is alpha software, i need something stable.

What is the best way to do this? Is there any library that does this already, Do i need to form my own HTTP requests?

Any advice on the subject is appreceated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up using the library at  http://www.local-guru.net/blog/pages/rubycaldav

I had to adapt it work with SSL, and use the UUID library correctly, format the dates correctly and work with Full day events. Since I only needed to create and destroy Events that is all i updated. I plan to do more with in when i have time.

My updated code can be found here https://github.com/loosecannon93/ruby-caldav.

The problem I was having was supplying incorrectly formatted dates, and lack of UUIDs.

The `caldavtest.rb` file on GitHub is what I used to work

An additional Complication i ran into was that Zimbra ( the server ) has 2 paths, one for ICS files that are readonly `/home/user@host/Calender` and one for CalDAV  `/dav/user@host/Calendar`

I hope that someone may find help with this solution.

However there is a substantial lack of cladav implementation for Ruby. There are ICS libraries that form objects, but there is only pure Net::HTTP to interact with a server. Local-guru's is the only ruby one I found that works both ways, but it is in need of some help with minor issues.

I fixed some of these but not project wide, I just had to get it working. But if someone would like to contribute I would love to help.

Answer (score 2):

One of my favorite places to check for possible options is on [Ruby Toolbox](http://ruby-toolbox.com/). This would be one of the first places I would check.

I would also check github, which yielded [this result](https://github.com/collectiveidea/caldav) which may be your best option and just what you are looking for.

As far as answering your other questions, I would probably roll my own after taking a look at both [this post](http://www.local-guru.net/blog/2009/03/29/javascript-caldav-frontend) and [this code](https://github.com/loosecannon93/ruby-caldav).

So, long answer severely shortened, yes there are libraries that already accomplish what you are looking to do, but if it were me, I would roll my own solution for something this specific.

Comment: haha, thanks for the reply, the "this code" link is actually to my solution ( i ended up rolling my own, based on some other stuff, dont really remeber this was a while ago )

Answer (score 0):

are you hosting your calendars on google? if you are, then take a look at: https://github.com/northworld/google_calendar

Comment: Duly Noted, alas however I am not.

Answer (score 0):

We've used [caldav4j](http://code.google.com/p/caldav4j/) as our app was deployed in JRuby. Don't know whether thats an option for you.